# Why xdg-open should not be used as root?

Tags: manpage, xdg-open

```
   **xdg-open is for use inside a desktop session only. It is not  
   recommended to use xdg-open as root.**
```

Why does the manual page say the above ?

Answer (score 2):

As you may know `xdg-open` is used to open a file or URL in the user's preferred application.

If you run it using `root`, you may end up with a broken system, but why?

Because you may run a graphical program using `root` access ( [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) ).

It may also run a program which shouldn't be run with `root` access or even accidentally run a dangerous command using `root` access.

`xdg-open` may simply run a command of which we are not sure of its results, so it shouldn't be run with `root` access.